# maven + cruisecontrol - slow builds

Tags: cruisecontrol, maven

I am running cruisecontrol with maven to build a Scala-project.

When I run mvn package outside cruisecontrol,the build takes less than 10 seconds, but when I invoke the build from cruisecontrol, the compilation-phase takes about 300 seconds. I am looking for hints and tips regarding how to speed up the compilation with maven.

One thing I have noticed is that CruiseControl keeps getting the error:
Failed to reach dashboard instance : http://localhost:8080/dashboard/buildloop/listener either the dashboard has not started up or there is a network problem.

When I google the problem, I see that it is frequent if you don't have a  in your config, but since I have this one, I am puzzled by this error.

My config.xml looks something like this:

```
<cruisecontrol>
        <project
                name="XXX" 
                buildafterfailed="false">
                <modificationset
                        quietperiod="30">
                        <svn 
                                LocalWorkingCopy="XXX"
                                username="XXX"
                                password="XXX" />
                </modificationset>
                <listeners></listeners>
                <bootstrappers>
                        <svnbootstrapper
                                localWorkingCopy="XXX"
                                username="XXX"
                                password="XXX" />
                </bootstrappers>
                <schedule 
                        interval="20">
                        <maven2
                                mvnhome="/opt/maven"
                                goal="clean package"
                                pomfile="XXX/XXX/checkout/trunk/pom.xml" />

                </schedule>
                <log dir="logs/remote-control-api-trunk">
                        <merge 
                                dir="XXX/XXX/checkout/trunk/target/surefire-reports/"
                                pattern="TEST-*.xml" />
                </log>
                <publishers>
                        <onsuccess>
                                <artifactspublisher
                                        file="/XXX/XXX/checkout/trunk/target/XXX.war"
                                        dest="/XXX/cruisecontrol/artifacts"
                                        />
                        </onsuccess>
                </publishers>
        </project>
</cruisecontrol>
```

Answer (score 0):

`config.xml` is doing `clean package` while you mentioned doing just `mvn package` outside cruise control. Try running `mvn clean package`.

Some other things you might want to check:

1. Maven versions used by cruise control and command line, are they same?
2. Maven super-pom/profiles active in both invocation